# Current extensions of the "Turing Test"?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, turing-test, ai-milestones, journalism

In 2014 it was widely reported that the Turing Test had been passed, and that this was a major AI milestone.

See: Computer AI passes Turing test in 'world first [[BBC]](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-27762088); Turing Test Success Marks Milestone in Computing History [[reading.ac.uk](http://www.reading.ac.uk/news-archive/press-releases/pr583836.html)]; What is the Turing test? And are we all doomed now? [[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/jun/09/what-is-the-alan-turing-test)]

Never mind that the "Imitation Game" is subjective, and that porn bots have been passing it since there were porn bots—University of Reading was clear about their metrics.

But I understand that it did lead to revised tests, and extension of thinking on what constitutes passing such a threshold.

- How have Turing Tests been extended since 2014?

How strong was the 2014 test?  What have been the criticisms of the 2014 determinations?

Comment: Anyone can read the wiki, but here I'm looking for expert answers that synopsize, ideally with links, and can comment on any limitations, or potential weaknesses in methology or theory of the widely publicized 2014 experiment.